# how to get last value from user input event and push into array react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

I have an Input component that creates as many input tags as needed based on JSON data.

I'm using the onChange method in the input tag and passing the event into a function "handleChange" using contextAPI to record the values in a different component.

I'm trying to then push that value into an array but when doing so it pushes every event the user presses let's say the user types in 450, when pushing array it comes out as ["4", "45", "450], how would I get the last value user puts?

Input component:

```
  const { handleChange } = useContext(FormContext);

  return (
    <input
      id={`input-text${id}`}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(id, e)}
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: `${fieldsPosX}px`,
        left: `${fieldsPosY}px`,
        background: "blue",
        border: "black",
        height: "30px",
        maxWidth: "70px",
        width: "100%",
        zIndex: "40",
        color: "#fff",
        textAlign: "center"
      }}
      maxLength={maxLength}
      type={"text"}
    />
  );
}

export default Input;
```

handleChange function:

```
  const handleChange = (id, e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);

    answers.push(e?.target?.value);
  };
```

Current output: `["4", "45", "450"]`

Expected output: `["450"]`

Comment: you have to use a `onBlur` like events or a debounce as given in the other post to handle it better

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a submit `<button>` as a trigger to push your user input to the array instead of just using the `<input>`. The `onChange` event track every change in the `<input>`, so every single change in there will trigger the `handleChange()` function. That's why everytime the user input a character it will trigger the `handleChange()` function.

Comment: Either this or you can use a Debounce with the long-running onChange event. You can then get the value when the user is probably done typing. But, this approach has the same problem if the user retypes. So better use the dispatch event.

Comment: Thank you for answering! i took the button submit mentioned and mixed it with the "name" type in the input tag and then went ahead and document.getElementsByName("test"); and bam got my unique values on button click * wish i could upvote but doesnt let me *